# Cannot iterate through collection

Tags: web-services, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

That's not it...

The problem lies somewhere in how I'm using the EF Customer model.

The definition of YeagerTechEntities() is as follows:

```
namespace YeagerTechModel
{
    public class YeagerTechEntities : ObjectContext
    {
        public YeagerTechEntities();
        public YeagerTechEntities(EntityConnection connection);
        public YeagerTechEntities(string connectionString);

        public ObjectSet<Customer> Customers { get; }

        public void AddToCustomers(Customer customer);
    }
}
```

The definition of DbContext.Customers is the following:

```
public ObjectSet<Customer> Customers { get; }
```

My method inside my service is defined as follows:

```
public IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomers()
        {
            YeagerTechEntities DbContext = new YeagerTechEntities();

            IEnumerable<Customer> customer = DbContext.Customers.Where(p => p.City.StartsWith("A"));
```

The above line gives me the following design time compile error.

```
Cannot implicity convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<YeagerTechModel.Customer> to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<YeagerTechWcfservice.Customer>'
```

This is partially because I have the following DataContract in my Interface for the Webservice which has the YeagerTechWcfservice namespace.

```
[DataContract]
    public class Customer
    {
        [DataMember]
        public Int16 CustomerID { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public String Email { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public String Company { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public String FirstName { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public String LastName { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public String Address1 { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public String Address2 { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public String City { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public String State { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public String Zip { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public String HomePhone { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public String CellPhone { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public String Website { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public String IMAddress { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    }
```

If I comment out the above interface class, the design time compile error goes away thinking that it's now using the class in my YeagerTechModel class which has my Customer object defined. I think this is the correct behaivor I want. However, when I try to run my service, I can't invoke the Getcustomers method because it has a red X next to it.

I feel I need to tell my web service to use my YeagerTechModel Customer class as the DataContract in the Interface, but don't know how to do that. Here is the Customer class I created in my YeagerTechModel project (which is a separate project, but in the same solution as the YeagerTechWcfService project).

How can I resolve this where my method will correctly cast the correct object in my GetCustomers webservice method?

```
[MetadataType(typeof(CustomerMetaData))]
    public partial class Customer
    {
    }

    public class CustomerMetaData
    {
        public object CustomerID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public object Email { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public object Company { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public object FirstName { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public object LastName { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public object Address1 { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public object Address2 { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public object City { get; set; }

        [StringLength(2)]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public object State { get; set; }

        [StringLength(10)]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public object Zip { get; set; }

        [StringLength(12)]
        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        public object HomePhone { get; set; }

        [StringLength(12)]
        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        public object CellPhone { get; set; }

        [StringLength(100)]
        [DataType(DataType.Url)]
        public object Website { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public object IMAddress { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public object CreatedDate { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public object UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding .ToList() on
IEnumerable<Customer> customer = DbContext.Customers.Where(p =>p.City.StartsWith("A")).ToList();

Comment: That's not it.... The problem lies in my full post above regarding the namespaces. The following statement gets the same error. IEnumerable<Customer> customer = DbContext.Customers.Where(p => p.CustomerID > 0).ToList(); If I change the left hand side to IEnumerable<YeagerTechModel.Customer> customer, the design time compile error goes away. I need to evaluate some more and then post...

Comment: Like I said before, I can't invoke this method in my web service with the SCT Test Client because it has a red X on it. It says "this operation is not supported in the WCF Test Client because it uses type YeagerTechModel.Customer[]".

Comment: So, how can I use the YeagerTechWcfService namespace instead of the YeagerTechModel namespace? If I use the YeagerTechWcfService namespace, I get the design time compile error. If I use the YeagerTechModel namespace, the design time compile error goes away, but can't invoke the method because of the above comment.

Comment: ah I see now. Ok - I can't comment too much on this as I always use my own sample app test clients to ensure functionality is working exactly as a consumer would use it. I've seen some postings on the net with the test app having issues with types - sorry I can't provide specifics here other than 'scrap it and simply add the references to your own sample app' . Without seeing all your service code is it possible that the contract is defined as YeagerTechWcfservice.Customer where you contain a different customer object defined in your code? if thats the case they should refer to the same object

Comment: What issues are you having in defining the correct Customer namespace to use in your service app?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the setup I used to resolve the issue:

YeagerTechModel project:
1.Add the System.ServiceModel & System.Runtime.Serialization namespaces.
2.Add The DataContract attribute for the Customer class and add the DataMember attribute for each property in the class which also supports DataAnnotations. This is a separate class from the EF generated class.

YeagerTechWcfService project:
1.This class will be used as the interface for the web service; not the one I originally declared in the project. I deleted that one. However, this will produce a rex X in the WCF Test Client tool. That's what was throwing me off. I can still use the setup I'm describing. It's just that I have to use another client (YeagTech project, which references this web service) to do the testing.
2.I can now use the following code snippet in the GetCustomers method to retrieve multiple customers.
3.IQueryable customer = DbContext.Customers.Where(p => p.CustomerID > 0);

4.In my Customer controller, I can now use the following code snippet to retrieve the data from the method in my web service:
5.IEnumerable customerList = db.GetCustomers();

6.My Customer view contains the following model:
7.@model IEnumerable

It works fine now!!!